# NSLocalNotification's repeating. Dismissing. Proper way

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to create a daily notification at 10AM with different content for every day.

```
func createNotification() {

let dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
dateComp.hour = 10; // supposed to run each day at 10AM

var myCalendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
var date:NSDate = myCalendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.fireDate = date
localNotification.alertBody = getContentStringForNotification() // Method returns different string for each date
localNotification.repeatInterval = .Day // Repeats every day
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
```

It duplicates notifications. They keep repeating and returning even yesterdays notifications. 
I searched through Stack Community questions, I did not find proper way to dismiss them.

As I understand:

- the app is terminated and they are scheduled and act independent of
  app. repeatedly running an app will create even more notifications.
- notifications are not properly dismissed and they return with
  yesterdays message even next day.

Help with:

1. What's a proper way to dismiss them or check if they have been fired
   already (making sure they don't repeat
2. Do I loop and create notifications for all year forth for each day or create a new one for tomorrow each time app is run

What am I missing? Code welcomed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're scheduling one notification in that code, with a single message, to be shown to the user once per day. If you run that code each time you open the app, or each day, you'll result in a lot of different notifications registered, each firing once per day and with some (possibly different) message.

You should be using `cancelAllLocalNotifications` or `cancelLocalNotification:` to remove old notifications.

Likely you don't want to set a repeat interval. Instead, each time the app is opened schedule 7 notifications on subsequent days for the next week. If the user hasn't used the app in 7 days you should probably stop bothering them with notifications (though you can register more up to the app limit).

Comment: Checking that: Should I write a last app run date in plist or there is a ready method for checking last run time?

Comment: you can, if you need to know it

Comment: Probably won't bother with that and just cancel them all and create new ones. Changed my code now and hope this works fine tomorrow. Will get back on this.

Comment: if you have a repeat interval set it to minute for testing. if you use explicit dates then you can log the registered notifications to verify them

Answer (score 6):

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = .Day // Repeats every day
```

This makes the notification automatically schedule for each day, so you shouldn't schedule new notification if you want to show the same notification (time and stuff).

If you want to reschedule the notification, first clear all previous local notification scheduled or read in the docs on how to clear a single UILocalNotification

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: Thanks for code line 'UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()'